# Why is id_cust_fb_cust undefined?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

I am playing with emberFire  / Ember Data but can't find why this code will not working ???
The var id_cust_ fb_cust is always undefined ?
When i look in ember inspector the query's works fine !
What am i doing wrong ???

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
 actions: {
     fixit: function() {
     var teller = 11;
     var _this = this;
     var strTeller = teller.toString();
    _this.store.findRecord('address',strTeller).then(function(address){
        var id_cust_presta_addr = address.get('id_customer');
        console.log('Id Customer Presta in address is :' + id_cust_presta_addr);
        _this.store.query('customer', {
                orderBy: 'id_customer',
                equalTo: id_cust_presta_addr
            }).then(function(customer){
                var id_cust_fb_cust = customer.get('email');
                console.log('Id Customer Presta in CUSTOMER is :' + id_cust_fb_cust + 'voor : ' + id_cust_presta_addr );
            })

    });
    } //fixit
} // actions
```

}); // export

Answer (score 0):

Use `_this.store.queryRecord` instead of `_this.store.query`

***UPDATE***

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
 actions: {
     fixit: function() {
     var teller = 11;
     var _this = this;
     var strTeller = teller.toString();
    _this.store.findRecord('address',strTeller).then(function(address){
        var id_cust_presta_addr = address.get('id_customer');
        console.log('Id Customer Presta in address is :' + id_cust_presta_addr);
        _this.store.query('customer', {
                orderBy: 'id_customer',
                equalTo: id_cust_presta_addr
            }).then(function(customers){
               //HERE : customers is array
                var customer = customers.objectAt(0);

                var id_cust_fb_cust = customer.get('email');
                console.log('Id Customer Presta in CUSTOMER is :' + id_cust_fb_cust + 'voor : ' + id_cust_presta_addr );
            })

    });
    } 
} 
});
```

Comment: I use emberfire and queryRecord is not implemented in this adapter

Comment: @RudiWerner I think `query` method returns array. So you need to handle this in in `then` part of calling `query`

Comment: I am new to javascript, Ember and emberfire? can you hint me how to do that ??  Thanks !

Comment: You have a typo @EbrahimPasbani, `var customer = customer.`, should be customers. You can also do `customers.get('firstObject')`.

Comment: @locks Thanks. Corrected now